# How to create a check box for a category to select all documents in that category?

Tags: xpages

I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796567/xpages-how-do-i-select-all-documents-in-a-categorized-column-of-a-view-control) already which never answers the question, how do put a check box on a category of a categorized view.  I have a view that has three levels of category's.  The first category is used as a filter for the view populated by a listbox / scope variable. The next category is year and the last is document type.

- **Client** ( filtered by scope variable from ListBox )

  - +**2010**
  - +**2011**
  - +**....**
  - -**2015**

    - -**Insurance**

      - Building COI
    - -**Bank Statements**

      - Jan statement
      - Feb statement
      - Mar statement
      - .....
  - +**2016**...

My end users want a check box on all levels so if they want all documents for 2015 they check the box next to 2015.  If they want all Bank Statements for 2015 they check the box next to Bank Statements under the 2015 category.  Or maybe they only want the one insurance document so they check the box next to the one document.

It seems I can't do this with the categorized view so what other options are available to create this categorized +/- ability and have check boxes at all levels?

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

They I would likely approach this is I would do 3 nested repeat controls.  Build it all manually and you get the most options.  You should be able to get whatever look and feel that you like.

In each of the repeats you have you're button that selects all the documents underneath it.  Now I'm a little unsure of the best way to "Select" the documents inside the repeat.  My button would be a direct processing button.  "Do This". And because I know what level it's on, using basically the same formula as the repeat control itself I can programmatically get a handle on all the documents in that category and then run whatever code I want.

My quick idea at least.